# nargin functionality (from Matlab) in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I am attempting to translate these lines of code:

```
error(nargchk(3, 4, nargin))
if nargout > 2, error('too many output parameters'); end
```

I want to translate it into Python. I have yet to find an equivalent for error (although I could perhaps just throw an exception here?), nargchk and nargin. Can anybody provide any input as to how this line of code can be translated?

Comment: Have you read the MATLAB documentation for the functions you're unsure of? Try to translate *functionality* not *functions*

Comment: If you consider that the *equivalent* of ```varargin``` is ```*args```, then ```nargin``` can be *translated* into ```len(args)``` in Python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing equivalent to `nargin` and `nargchk` because Python doesn't need it.  You can define optional arguments in Python directly in the function definition.  So for example:

```
def myfunc(a=1, b=3):
```

In this case it lets you set `a` and `b` to whatever you want, but if you don't define them it uses the default values you specified.  So if you call `myfunc()`, it sets `a` to `1` and `b` to 3.  If you call `myfunc(5)` it sets `a` to `5` and `b` to `3`.  You can also call by name, such as `myfunc(b=10)`, which sets `a` to `1` and `b` to 10.

If you want argument to be required, just don't assign anything to them in the function definition.  So in the following case, `a` is required while `b` is optional:

```
def myfunc(a, b=3):
```

If you want a user to be able to specify an arbitrary number of arguments, you can use `*args` (where `args` can be whatever variable you want.  So this:

```
def myfunc(a=1, b=3, *args):
```

Will assign the first argument to `a`, the second argument to `b`, and any remaining arguments to `args`.  You can also do this with arguments defined by name using `**kwargs` (again, `kwargs` can be any variable name).  So this:

```
def myfunc(a=1, b=3, *args, **kwargs):
```

Does the same thing as the previous one, but any arguments provided by name other than `a` and `b` will go in `kwargs` (which is a dictionary).

So you don't need `nargin` and `nargchk`, generally you can just define the arguments you need and set default values for the optional ones.  Then Python will automatically handle checking to make sure the required options are specified and there aren't too many arguments provided.  If you need to capture an arbitrary number of additional arguments, just use `*args` and `**kwargs` and you can check that the `len` is correct yourself.

For `nargout`, there is no python equivalent because python requires all outputs be handled.  So if you do `return a, b`, in `myfun`, `a`, and `b` must both be handled.  You can simply ignore some, but you must explicitly do this.  There is no easy way to check if those arguments are being ignored.  So say we have this in `myfunc`:

```
return a, b, c, d
```

And you only want `a`, you can just do:

```
a, *_ = myfunc()
```

This puts the first returned value in `a` and dumps the remainder in the throw-away variable `_` (just like `*args` captures all remaining arguments, `*_` captures all remaining outputs).  For, say, `a` and `c`, you can do:

```
a, _, c, _ = myfunc()
```

You can also index directly from a function call, something MATLAB doesn't allow.  So this is also possible.  So to get the first argument, you can do:

```
a = myfunc()[0]
```

So since it is easy in Python to get the returned values you want, and since implicit variable numbers of output values is an extreme pain to handle properly, Python doesn't support it.  If you really want to change the number of output argument you can set an optional named argument in the function definition to do so.  Since optional arguments are easy in Python, this isn't a huge issue.  But it isn't usually needed.

As for errors, yes you just `raise` the appropriate exception.  Python has different types of errors for different situations.  `raise TypeError('blah')` is the correct approach for the wrong number of arguments, where `blah` is the message you want.

Comment: Having a background in Matlab but little Python knowledge I found your answer very informative, +1