# Returning variables Matlab and Python?

Tags: python, matlab, input, output

I am trying to translate some code from Matlab to Python. The start of my function (in Matlab) starts like this:

```
function [varargout]=hysime(varargin);
    error(nargchk(3, 4, nargin))
    if nargout > 2, error('too many output parameters'); end
    verbose = 1; % default value
    y = varargin{1}; % 1st parameter is the data set
```

Later in the program there is something like this:

```
n = varargin{2}; % the 2nd parameter is the noise
Rn = varargin{3}; % the 3rd parameter is the noise correlation matrix

if nargin == 4, verbose = ~strcmp(lower(varargin{4}),'off');end
```

and finally there is this:

```
varargout(1) = {kf};
if nargout == 2, varargout(2) = {Ek};end
return
```

I am incredibly confused about what this code means. On one hand I understand that the parameters inputed all need to be returned. However, at the end of the program it appears like only 2 variables will be returned (while we input 3?). How can I translate this code so that the necessary parameters are returned? I guess my biggest issue here is that the matlab code is letting the agent input the parameters however they do not all seem required? And it seems like there cannot be more than two outputs? I am just having trouble deciphering what each line of code here means. Can someone please provide an explanation both in what is happening with the matlab code and what I can do to make the same sort of functionality in python?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure what most of the outputs are supposed to be, given that there's an explicit error if there are more than 2 outputs specified. Either address the purpose of the program with whoever wrote it in the first place, or just make your Python code output what *you* need it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short version**

The MATLAB code should have been written like this:

```
function [kf, Ek]=hysime(y, n, Rn, verbose);
    error(nargchk(3, 4, nargin))
    if nargin < 4
        verbose = true;
    else
        verbose = ~strcmpi(verbose ,'off');
    end
```

If you know MATLAB, this should be clearer.  The (mostly) corresponding Python code can be written like this:

```
def hysime(y, n, Rn, verbose=True):
    # rest of the function here
    return kf, Ek
```

**Long Version**

This function expects 3 or 4 input arguments, with a default value set if the fourth argument is not provided.  However, it is done in a way that is much more complicated than it needs to be (although I see this pattern a lot).  Ideally in MATLAB you would specify the same thing like this:

```
function [varargout]=hysime(y, n, Rn, verbose)
    error(nargchk(3, 4, nargin))
    if nargin < 4
        verbose = true;
    else
        verbose = ~strcmpi(verbose ,'off');
    end
```

So what it is doing is putting the first argument in the variable `y`, the second in the variable `n`, the third in `Rn`, and if the fourth is specified put it in `verbose` (based on how it compares to the string `'off'`), otherwise set `verbose` to `true`.

In python, handling of optional arguments is built-in.  You can specify default value for arguments right in the function definition by setting `name=value`, where `name` is the argument name and `value` is the default value.  Also, for historical reasons MATLAB often uses `'on'` and `'off'` instead of `true` and `false`.  This is almost never done in Python, people just use `True` and `False`.  So you can specify the same thing in Python like so:

```
def hysime(y, n, Rn, verbose=True):
```

This makes `y`, `n`, and `Rn` required arguments, but lets `verbose` be optional.

This doesn't handle the case where `verbose` is set to the string `'off'`.  As I said, this is common in MATLAB for historical reasons, but you really shouldn't be doing it in MATLAB anymore when you can avoid it, and you definitely shouldn't be doing it in Python.  But if you really, really need to handle that case, you can just do:

```
def hysime(y, n, Rn, verbose=True):
    if isinstance(verbose, str):
        verbose = verbose.lower() != 'off'
```

For the output, what the MATLAB code does is let the function either return one value or two.  So someone could do this:

```
kf = hysime(y, n, Rn);
```

Or

```
[kf, Ek] = hysime(y, n, Rn);
```

However, this is also being done in a way that is more complicated than necessary.  If you just return the two values, and only one return value is used, MATLAB will throw away the rest.  So rather than messing around with `varargout`, the function could just return `[kf, Ek]` and MATLAB will do the same thing.  An error will automatically occur if someone tries to call the function with more than 2 outputs as well, so that is also unnecessary.

Dealing with `varargout` in this way is only necessary if you want the program to change its behavior based on the number of outputs.  In this sort of structure, the main reason you would do this is if `eK` was expensive to calculate, in which case you would do something like this:

```
varargout(1) = {kf};
if nargout == 2
    # calculate eK here
    varargout(2) = {Ek};
end
```

As for the `return`, that is only needed in MATLAB if you want to cause the function to stop early, before it reaches the end normally.  Once it reaches the end normally, it will `return` automatically.  So if the last block of code you specified is the end of the function, then the `return` is redundant.

So all the code you showed in MATLAB can be reduced to:

```
function [kf, Ek]=hysime(y, n, Rn, verbose);
    error(nargchk(3, 4, nargin))
    if nargin < 4
        verbose = true;
    else
        verbose = ~strcmpi(verbose ,'off');
    end
```

As for Python, as I mentioned in my [other answer to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407867/3604159), Python requires all returned values be handled.  It will never throw away returned values unless you explicitly tell it to.  In your case, the simplest solution is just to have `return kf, Ek` at the end of the function.  If someone wants both `kf` and `Ek`, they can do:

```
kf, Ek = hysime(y, n, Rn)
```

If they only want `kf`, they can do (where `_` is the python convention for a variable you don't care about):

```
kf, _ = hysime(y, n, Rn)
```

Or:

```
kf = hysime(y, n, Rn)[0]
```

So the python code would be:

```
def hysime(y, n, Rn, verbose=True):
    # rest of the function here
    return kf, Ek
```

If you really want to be able to have one or two returned values, you would need to have another argument to change the behavior.  Such as:

```
def hysime(y, n, Rn, verbose=True, ret_eK=False):
    # rest of the function here
    return (kf, Ek) if ret_eK else kf
```

So in this case if the `ret_eK` argument is specified and set to `True`, then `kf, Ek` is returned, otherwise just `kf` is returned.  But in Python you really don't want to do this unless there is some major additional cost to calculating `Ek`, which doesn't appear to be in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your previous answer was also very clear and detailed; I was only confused because I was not sure what the Matlab code was really trying to do. This was very helpful to my work!

Comment: Actually, you don’t need `varargout` in the case of an optional output argument either. You can, in the function, only assign something to the 2nd output argument if `nargout>1`. `varargout` is useful only when you don’t know how many output arguments you’ll have (see `deal` for example).